# group by + lookup in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have three different mongoose collection as follow :

**TranslationModel**

```
[{
  "_id" : 5e009858efbbba65a24c222b,
  "lable" : 5e009858efbbba65a24c2229,
  "language" : 5dfcc3f92dec0f2d2bdd0226,
  "translation" : تسجيل الدخول
}, {
  "_id" : 5e009858efbbba65a24c222d,
  "lable" : 5e009858efbbba65a24c2229,
  "language" : 5dfcc520c2e7bb31dcb03058,
  "translation" : login
}, {
  "_id" : 5e009858efbbba65a24c222f,
  "lable" : 5e009858efbbba65a24c2229,
  "language" : 5dfcc804b2d85c3e63a7159f,
  "translation" : התחברות
}]
```

LablesModel

```
{
  "_id":"5e009858efbbba65a24c2229"
  "lableKey":"login",
  "lable":"login"
}
```

LanguageModel

```
[{
  "_id":"5dfcc520c2e7bb31dcb03058",
  "isActive":true,
  "code":"en",
  "name":"English",
  "createdAt":"1576846624151"
}, {
  "_id":"5dfcc3f92dec0f2d2bdd0226",
  "isActive":true,
  "code":"ar",
  "name":"Arabic",
  "createdAt":"1576846624151"
}, {
  "_id":"5dfcc804b2d85c3e63a7159f",
  "isActive":true,
  "code":"he",
  "name":"Hebrew",
  "createdAt":"1576847364305"
}]
```

I'm trying to aggregate them but i cant get below result :

```
[{
  lable: "login",
  lableKey: "login",
  translation: [{
    translation: "login",
    language:"english"
  }, {
    {
    translation: "تسجيل الدخول",
    language:"Arabic"
  }, {
    translation: "התחברות",
    language:"Hebrew"
  }]
}]
```

Is it even possible ?
if yes please help me alredy i west my more time

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i used group by and lookup but i cant get my array properly

Comment: Why did you make your schema so relational. You are using mongodb but your tables are relational